# Error parsing Passengerfile.json settings during preparation work

Tags: meteor, passenger

When trying to start my meteor application through passenger, I am recieivng the following error;

> The Phusion Passenger application server tried to start the web >application, but Passenger encountered an internal error while performing >preparation work.
>
> Error details:
>
> Error parsing /var/www/timportDB/bundle/Passengerfile.json: * Line 9, Column 16
>     Missing '}' or object member name

```
 in 'Passenger::AppLocalConfig Passenger::parseAppLocalConfigFile(Passenger::StaticString)' (AppLocalConfigFileUtils.h:102)
 in 'void Passenger::SpawningKit::Spawner::setConfigFromAppPoolOptions(Passenger::SpawningKit::Config*, Passenger::Json::Value&, const AppPoolOptions&)' (Spawner.h:83)
 in 'virtual Passenger::SpawningKit::Result Passenger::SpawningKit::DirectSpawner::spawn(const AppPoolOptions&)' (DirectSpawner.h:242)
 in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (SpawningAndRestarting.cpp:95)
```

Originally it seemed to be related to where I set the envvars, however I have commented them out and set them using command line variables rather then the settings file.

These variables are ```--envvar MONGO_URL=mondgodb://localhost:27017/timportDB --envar ROOT_URL=http://timportDB

According to the passenger guide the program should be run with `sudo passenger start`

The program is being run on Ubuntu 18.04.03.LTS. I am using the standalone version of Passenger

This is my Passengerfile.json;

```
{
  // Tell Passenger that this is a Meteor app.
  "app_type": "node",
  "startup_file": "main.js",
  // Store log and PID file in parent directory
  "log_file": "../passenger.log",
  "pid_file": "../passenger.pid"
  // Run the app in a production environment. The default value is "development".
  "environment": "production",
  // Run Passenger on port 80, the standard HTTP port.
  "port": 80,
  // Tell Passenger to daemonize into the background.
  "daemonize": true,
  // Tell Passenger to run the app as the given user. Only has effect
  // if Passenger was started with root privileges.
  "user": "timportdb",
  //better errors
  "friendly_error_pages":true
//  "envvars": {"MONGO_URL": "mongodb://localhost:27017/timportDB", "ROOT_URL": "http://timportDB",}
}
```

When the program starts I should be able to access my web app at 0.0.0.0:80, or (Assuming DNS has been set correctly) at 'http://timportDB'.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

This is a rookie problem (no offence intended)

The json file format does not allow any kind of comments, it is a data only format.

So to fix this, delete all lines beginning with `//`